# How to prove that $3ab(a+b)$ cannot be a cube?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the diophantine equation: $ 3ab(a+b)=c^3 $ where $a,b,c$ are non-zero integers,how do you prove that this equation has no integral solutions?

Comment: This is equivalent to $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+c^3$

Comment: You mean "no nonzero solutions"?

Comment: yes. I attempted this method but i feel like i am turning in circle. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Where do you got this problem from?

Comment: I saw it on the web. I cannot find it anymore. The blogger must have deleted it.

Here is what I came up with: $x^3 -y^3 =(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$ 
Let $ p=x-y$, then, $ x^3-y^3=p[(p+y)^2+(p+y)y+y^2]$

$x^3-y^3= p[p^2+2py+y^2+py+y^2+y^2]$

$x^3-y^3=p^3+3p^2y+3y^2p $

$x^3-y^3=p^3+3py(p+y) $

Which implies, $x^3=y^3+p^3+ 3py(p+y)$. According to Ramanujan,there are solutions for $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$. Therefore, I cannot see why the expression $3py(p+y)$ cannot be a cube.

Comment: $3^3+4^3+5^3=6^3$

Comment: @metacompactness, and what? $6\ne 3+4,~~ 6\ne 3+5,~~ 6\ne 4+5$. RHS here must be $(a+b)^3$.

Comment: @Oleg567 I was just giving an example of Andy's claim that $a^3+b^3+c^3=d^3$ has a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edition/Revision 2.**

Equation
$$
3ab(a+b) = c^3
$$
**has** non-zero integer solutions.

One of "obvious" solutions is 
$$
(a,b,c) = (1,8,6);\tag{A}
$$
other (not so obvious) sulutions that I've found so far, are:
$$
(a,b,c) = (3087, 4913,7140) \\ 
\color{gray}{ = (9 \cdot 7^3, 17^3, 3 \cdot 7\cdot 17 \cdot 20)},\tag{B}
$$
$$
(a,b,c) = (756249048, 19902511, 327250386) \\
\color{gray}{ = (9 \cdot 438^3, 271^3, 3 \cdot 438 \cdot 271 \cdot 919)},\tag{C}
$$
$$
(a,b,c) = (6646883738818239, 48707103808000, 1866552387462840) \\
\color{gray}{ = (9 \cdot 90391^3, 36520^3, 3 \cdot 90391 \cdot 36520 \cdot 188479)}.\tag{D}
$$

These solutions can be represented as sum of $3$ cubes (as **metacompactness** noted in comments to the question):
$$
\color{gray}{a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (a+b)^3;}\\
\color{gray}{1^3 + 8^3 + 6^3 = (1+8)^3 = 9^3;}\\
\color{gray}{3087^3 + 4913^3 + 7140^3 = (3087+4913)^3 = 8000^3;}\\
...
$$

---

Here I consider only solutions with co-prime $a,b$. (It is clear why).

---

Way to find solutions:

we'll focus on **co-prime** $a,b$.

If $3| c^3$, then $27| c^3$, then $9| ab(a+b)$.

$3$ cases are here:
**A)** $9\mid a, \quad 3\nmid b$;
**A')** $3\nmid a, \quad 9\mid b$; (symmetric to case A) )
**B)** $3\nmid a, \quad 3\nmid b, \quad 9\mid (a+b)$.

**case A)**:

$a,b,(a+b)$ are co-prime pairwice.
So, $a,b,(a+b)$ have different prime factors.
Then every of numbers $3a, b, (a+b)$ has each prime factor in $3\times$ power.
Other words, $3a,b,(a+b)$ are co-prime cubes:

$$3a = 27 p^3,\qquad b = q^3, \qquad (a+b) = r^3.$$

Then
$$3ab(a+b) = 27p^3q^3r^3 = (3pqr)^3.$$ 
$$c = 3pqr.$$
Thus for searching $(a,b,c)$ one needs to consider co-prime pairs $(p,q)$, such that
$$
9p^3+q^3 = r^3.\tag{*}
$$

Triple $(p,q,r) = (7,17,20)$ generates solution $(B)$,
triple $(p,q,r) = (438,271,919)$ generates solution $(С)$,
triple $(p,q,r) = (90391,36520,188479)$ generates solution $(D)$.

**case B)**:

Similar thinking. 
$a,b,3(a+b)$ are co-prime cubes:

$$a = p^3,\qquad b = q^3, \qquad 3(a+b) = 27r^3. $$

Then
$$ab\cdot3(a+b) = 27p^3q^3r^3 = (3pqr)^3.$$

Thus for searching $(a,b,c)$ one needs to consider co-prime pairs $(p,q)$, where $3\nmid p$ and/or $3\nmid q$, such that
$$
p^3+q^3 = 9r^3.\tag{**}
$$

Triple $(p,q,r)=(1,2,1)$ generates solution $(A)$.

Comment: That first line should say $3 \cdot 1 \cdot 8 \cdot (1+8) = 216 = 6^3$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542, yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Next question: Is there a finite number of solutions? Just curious.

Comment: I'm really intrigued of this question (for coprime $a,b$, of course).

Comment: @metacompactness, looking at formula $(*)$, and looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture, one can see that *quality* of each triple $(9p^3,q^3,r^3)$ is $>1$: 
$$q(9\cdot 7^3,17^3,20^3)=\frac{3\cdot\log(20)}{\log(3\cdot 7\cdot 17\cdot 2\cdot 5)}\approx 1.0986;\\
q(9\cdot 438^3,271^3,919^3)=\frac{3\cdot\log(919)}{\log(3\cdot 2\cdot 73\cdot 271\cdot 919)}\approx 1.10602;\\
...$$
So, each solution of main equation is related to ABC-triple with $q(A,B,C)>1$. Set of such triples isn't rich. 
So, the set of solutions of this equation (with coprime $a,b$) isn't rich (maybe it is finite).

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable inputs. I had a feeling that there were non-zero solutions but I could not figure out why.

Comment: @Oleg567, Just out of curiosity, How did do generate the solutions( D for instance) with large numbers? Did you use a computer program?

Comment: @Andy, yes, for generating solutions (C) and (D) I used program  based on formula $(*)$. It takes all (not very large) pairs $(p,q)$, that $3\nmid q$, and checks whether $9p^3+q^3$ is a cube.